# evento onclick boton generado por array

Tags: javascript, ajax, array, botón

tengo el siguiente codigo, y quiero que que al hacer click el boton execute la funcion del onclik con el parametro indicado.

```
function getcontent() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://example.io/blog',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result) {
        var blog = [];
        $.each(result, function(key, content) {
            blog.push("<div class='article'>");       
            blog.push("<a class='titol'>" + content.titol + "</a>");
            blog.push("<p class='autor'>" + content.autor + "</p>");
            blog.push("<p class='data'>"+content.data+"</p>");
            blog.push("<div class='content'>"+content.contingut+"</div>");
            blog.push('<button onclick="getcontentById("'+content.id+'")">more</button>');
            blog.push("</div>");
        });

        $("#content").empty();
        $("#content").html(blog.join(""));
    }
});
}
```

Comment: a que parámetro te refieres?

Comment: a ejecutar getcontentById() con content.id

Comment: Puedes envolverlo dentro de: $("#mielemento").click(funtion(){//Aqui dentro tu codigo que se ejecuta cuando dan click});

Comment: Probaste con quitar la comilla doble? `'+content.id+'` en lugar de `"'+content.id+'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo solucione usando un passando la id via enlace i en html usar una funcion de javascript:

```
blog.push("<a href='detall.html?id="+content.id+"' target='_blank'>more</a>");
```